# How to store the "result" of ORDER_BY in a field?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Here's the scenario - I have a bunch of identically structured tables, each containing between a million to a few billion rows. In the front end, the user must be able to select a range of these rows and modify them in bulk. The user is also able to select the ordering of the rows, sometimes based on the value of multiple fields, therefore this range that I must modify in the table is dependent on some specific ORDER_BY statement.

My intuitive idea on how to solve this is to somehow place the index according to user specified ORDER_BY statement into a field in the table for every single row of the table and then I can use this index field to construct a WHERE statement and do my update.

I don't know how though or even what to google for, does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you provide a more specific example of what you need to accomplish?  It sounds like you're trying to update a different subset of data by altering `ORDER_BY`, but from my understanding, only the `WHERE` clause will affect which rows get updated, not `ORDER_BY` 

Comment: The question is unclear. ORDER BY doesn't produce any results or specifies ranges, it sorts the query results. Indexes already exist on a table, they aren't created for each query. Indexes can speed up the entire query, including ordering the results.

Comment: `In the front end` that means the user only sees a single page of data at a time, not billions of rows. Create indexes that cover the common filter and ordering options to allow quick loading of the 1-2 pages of data that are shown to users.

Comment: I'm not sure sqlite is the best choice for billions of rows tables.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is the Row_number() function. it lets you create a numeric column from the result of ordering and optionally partitioning the data.

```
select column1,column2,Row_Number() over (order by column2) as RN
```

[Reference](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-row_number/)